# How to create buttons like style with contents inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently came across the site: https://www.airbnb.com/locations/new-york/neighborhoods

Which has a really nice feature where each LI has a button and some span inside it.

I tried to emulate the same but wasn't able to find all the styling.

This is what I have so far:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.btn {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.4em 1.2em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 0px #000;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #00AEFF 0%, #018FE1 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    border-image: none;
    border-color: #0195EB #0083C7 #0175B8;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn.large {
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0.6em 1.3em;
}
.btn:link, .btn:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}
.traits li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.traits li {
    margin: 0px 8px 11px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
<ul id="trait_selector" class="traits">
    <li class="trait" data-trait-id="66">
        <a class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="66" href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=66">
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="name"></span>
            <span class="count"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="trait" data-trait-id="8">
        <a class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="8" href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=8"></a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Which definitely doesn't look anything like the added link.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: So, you used your browser's element inspector tool and could not find all of the CSS information related to the elements on that website? Please consider setting up a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I checked the developer account and not all the styling is displayed.

Comment: It was confusing me as well...

Comment: You seem to only take the `-moz-` variants. If you are looking at your result in Firefox, it would not matter, but, just in case.

Comment: how about http://jsfiddle.net/Hp3MH/

Comment: @Banana WHATTTTT? :) How did you? What did you? hmmmmmm

Comment: just copied the whole ul, and the whole style sheet. now just isolate the styles you need, and delete the irrelevant ones

Comment: Maybe you want to "answer" it, so I can accept it?

Comment: will do, ill just isolate the relevant styles and ill post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp3MH/1/)

copied their entire `<ul>` element, and the whole style sheet,

i removed most of the irrelevant styles, just go through whats left and remove the ones that are irrelevant to the user list.

Comment: @Banana... For some reason my code is not working correctly in IE while the website one is. Any idea?

Comment: yea, make sure you use correct browser directives, like `-webkit-` for chrome, safari and comodo dragon, `-moz-` for firefox, `-ms-` fore IE, and `-o-` for opera, some attributes like gradient need to be prefixed with the browser directive `-webkit-gradient` for example.

Comment: I just copied the same exact stylesheet without deleting anything. :/ Maybe it has to be online for it work?

Comment: its weird, their website doesnt work for me on IE 11. i did have a look at their style sheet though, they use `-webkit-` and `-moz-` directives, but not `-ms-`. did you isolate the relevant styles? try adding an `-ms-` attribute to every style that has the webkit and moz ones

Comment: Seems to be working for me in IE9... Not exactly the same but still close enough and it doesn't make the dark blue color.

Comment: It was the way the gradient was set up on their site that I copied. I re did the gradient and it's fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="checkbox.png" alt=""/>Menuitem</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span class="checkbox"></span>Menuitem</a></li>
</ul>

.checkbox {
    background: url(images/checkbox.png);
}
```